# Magento - display product reviews on product view page

Tags: magento, templates

I am having difficulty placing the product reviews on the main product view at a specific location. I can load them in the content area, but not at the specific location I require (within some of the view mark-up).

I have a local.xml with the following in it:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content"> 
         <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml"/>
    </reference>
<catalog_product_view>
```

The above loads the reviews after all other content - as might be expected, due to content not being a templated block.

I have tried defining the blocks outside of the content reference, and placing this at the relevant point:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reviews') ?>
```

For clarity, here is where I need the block to appear in view.phtml:

```
<div class="product-collateral">
<?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
    <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
        <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
        <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php echo $html; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reviews') ?>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't output anything at all. I'm fairly new to Magento, and I'm at a loss how to achieve the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try leaving the code as in your example and include and use the attribute before, or after. 
This allows you to position a block in regards to another block within that reference.

Ex: `<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" before="product.description"/>`

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get your method to work in my context. Basically, I want to add the block within the `<div class="product-collateral"></div>` within the view.phtml mark-up - I've tried `after="product_info_additional"` but it doesn't work. I have amended my question with further info.

Comment: Ok, i've looked into the problem a bit. Took the example from layout/tag.xml. Basically you'll want to change the reference name from "content" to "product.info.additional". This will include the block in the specific div. Afterwards it should be easy to juggle the position with the before and after attributes.

Comment: That's worked, thank you! I have another related question now, perhaps you can take a look - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277522/magento-using-content-block-in-different-context-and-getchildhtml-not-working]