# Magento - using content block in different context and getChildHtml not working

Tags: magento, templates

I am loading the product review block, which is normally found on its own page, on to the main product view (related question [Magento - display product reviews on product view page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272618/magento-display-product-reviews-on-product-view-page/19273887)).

This is working correctly except that the add review form which is located in the `review/product/view/list.phtml` block ( called via `$this->getChildHtml('review_form')` ) isn't loading into the view. Presumably it's to do with the context, but I'm unsure how to fix this.

Is it possible to "instantiate" this `review_form` block within the reviews by adding something to my local.xml file?

For clarity, I don't want to just load the review_form block into my product view, I need it to load in the reviews block (in the correct location in its markup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can just load the review/form block: `<block type="review/form" template="review/form.phtml" />`

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't seem to work for me - where should I be placing it in the local.xml file? I tried in `<catalog_product_view>` but nothing appears, and if I add it to `<reference name="product.info.additional">` it does appear, but not in the correct place (I need it to exist in the same place it is called within the products reviews block. I have amended my question to clarify.

Comment: Right, I have this working now - I figured out that I needed to place the block code within the parent reviews block in my local.xml file. Thanks!